# DataSet QueryTableAdapter can't return tabular data

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

So this is more of a curiosity question (I have a simple enough work around), but I am wondering why I can not add a query to a QuerytableAdapter in a dataset that will return tabular data.

It allows me to use a query that returns a single value or none at all, but the option to return tabular data is always greyed out.

Now, my work around is pretty simple, I just using a tableAdapter instead, and voila! it works just fine.

I am using Studio 2008 and SQL server 2008 r2

Thanks

EDIT:

I should state that same goes for stored procedures as well.

a guess I have is because tableadapters create a datatable to go along with the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I do honestly hope you're not struggling with this seven years later, but the answer is to add a `TableAdapter` instead of a `Query` in the designer. It will still give you the option to run a stored procedure but will return your data in a table.